# Should i put an index on my DATE-field?

Tags: mysql, date, indexing

I'm designing a whole new database. There would be a lot of queries going on each day. It's actually a very,very simple time-accounting system but I still want to be as fast as possible. I'm building it myself because I can, and I could save som money and at the same time get it exactly how I want, just to get a grasp of time that I'm consuming in different projects.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `activity` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `activity_date` date NOT NULL,
  `minutes` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'time for this activity (in minutes)
  `week_nr` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'store weeknr for faster selection',
  `year_nr` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'store yearnr for fast selection',
  `month_nr` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'store monthnr for faster selection',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `week_nr` (`week_nr`),
  KEY `year_nr` (`year_nr`),
  KEY `month_nr`, (`month_nr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci COMMENT='Table for storing activities' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

When user is saving an activity in the table above, then my thought is to update **year_nr**, **week_nr** and **month_nr** for the typed-in activity_date so the system easily could get a report for activities between, lets say week 5 and 10, or between month 5 (May) and month 10 (October).

Is this a good idea or is better to just put an index on the date-field? My prediction is that would be a lot more select-queries going on, then it would be updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite easy considering the following tip:

> Write queries for continuous periods as explicit range condition.

Example from 2013 till 2014:

```
WHERE activity_date >= '2013-01-01' and activity_date < '2015-01-01'
```

All you need to do is to calculate the boundary dates and then use this pattern. This pattern can use a straight index on `activity_date` — no additional columns/indexes needed. It works as long as you need to query a continuous period of time (as opposed to "every monday" which are scattered periods of time).

Don't apply any functions to indexed columns. Don't `YEAR(activity_date)` that's the anti-pattern to avoid :)

Reference: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/dates

Comment: Ok, thanks! I used a rather simple example just to simplify - but what if I would like to query something like activities between week 51 2013 and week 2 2014 ? I guess the way to go would NOT to have YEAR() and WEEK() - functions involved - based on your reasoning.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld It's always the same game: (1) determine the boundary dates [2013-12-16 — 2014-01-13[; (2) use the WHERE clause as shown above. Any way to determine the boundary dates is fine, also in the client app! I've just used google now ;)

Comment: Of course I could create these boundaries in PHP (which is my main language (besides from swedish ;-)) but wouldn't this create a overhead in comparision to just use the db with select-statements?

Comment: You are thinking at the wrong scale! Calculating the boundary dates takes "a few" CPU cycles. Having a single index that you can use for all queries saves you gigabytes (depends on the table size, of course) of storage and is much better cachable and equally fast queried. It's really the better appraoch and you have all options in the future to make strange queries. E.g. like wednesday to wednesday queries.

Comment: Aha. That seems a LOT of sense! Thanks a LOT for your input! You have just earned an acceptance of an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think its a bad idea. You should build a index on date field rather..

Comment: I would like to know WHY you think that? Wouldn't it be faster to retrieve activities between 2013 and 2014 with SELECT * FROM activity WHERE year_nr>=2013 AND year_nr<=2014 rather then SELECT * FROM activity WHERE YEAR(activity_date)>=2013 AND YEAR(activity_date)<=2014 ?